# Colon in grunt compress task compiles goes as slash

Tags: compression, gruntjs

I use grunt-contrib-compress.

This is my task:

```
compress: {
    main: {
        options: {
            archive: '<%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM") %>.zip',
            mode: 'zip'
        },
        files: [{
            src: ['css/**', 'img/**', 'js/**', '*.html']
        }]
    }
},
```

Take a look to file name. I wrote `HH:MM`, but it is compressed to `pkgname 18.08.2014 10/42.zip`

How to make file name with colon instead of slash?